# How to manage virtual currency transactions

Tags: databases, economy

I am developing a game that needs a transaction management system.

Once player finish a task, he or she would gain some amount of credits (virtual money).

When Player_A buys some virtual things from Player_B, some amount of credits would be reduced from Player_A's account. Simultaneously, the same amount of credits would be added to Player_B.

Is there a standard method I can use, or open system to manage this kind of thing?.

Comment: Does this need to do more than just keep track of how much money your player has in your game? If so, this is such a simple task that it would surprise me if anyone bothered to create an asset for this. Or do you want it to be able to do more? Then please describe your requirements in detail.

Comment: This is one of the simplest use case of a backend server. Your server code will store player balances, when one creates a transaction and when the other accepts it. As it is often the example used for starter tutorials in database and server-side software, you will find a bazillion tutorials online on any language possible.

Comment: Are you talking from a online game? If so then there is much more to take care off than just creating a DB transaction and unroll it.

Comment: @user743414 yes, it is an online game. I found some open projects on github, i don't know which one is better

Comment: Which one is better depends on your exact needs.